# How to get XChat to automatically "ghost" the old "session" on provider-forced reconnect?

Tags: xchat

My provider forces a re-connect all 24h, which breaks my XChat session. Though the connection usually is re-established within seconds, due to the changed IP the "old session" is invalidated. XChat automatically joins the network(s), but then my nick gets refused as it "is already in use". I can manually solve that by "/nickserv ghost MyUser MyPass" -- but I could not find any place to configure XChat to do that automatically. Is that possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is based off my SU answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/302399/10165)

Assuming all versions work the same, you can put /msg nickserv ghost name password as a connect command under server settings for freenode.

[image]

To change your nick as well is a little tricky - type in

> /msg nickserv ghost username password

Then [CTRL SHIFT u a](http://xchat.org/faq/#q214)

> /nick username

As one line. This should do both commands one after another.

Comment: The OP is looking for an automatic thing, like a plugin to do the job when they are not there. Funnily enough that was mentioned in the SU answer.

Comment: I do seem to recall it did so during my testing, i should be no different from if he pinged out and reconnected (where this works)

Comment: Hope it does then - I know someone else might be interested :)

Comment: If and only if its in the connect commands will it work.  :)

Comment: Which is what the answer says. Added a screenshot for clarity. The trick is really in getting *multiple* connect commands to ghost and change name at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to have done it! I didn't even need to combine two commands as you described: Simply put the nickserv password in the corresponding field (I had it there before) seems to be enough. When I returned to XChat *after* the re-connect, it still showed my "original" nick and not (as before) the "reserve" one.

So again to make it clear:
 * in the "connect command" field, place `/nickserv ghost <nickname> <password>` (of course replacing <nickname> and <password> with the real data
 * put your nickserv password in the "nickserv password" field

Comment: Looks like it sometimes works and other times not. I already put in the "connected" command (could no longer edit my previous comment to adjust that, it seems in fact to be needed). Worked the first time ("...is ghosted...you are now known as..."). But today, only the ghosting worked. Si in case the reason is it fired the commands to fast, I changed the second command to `/timer 5 nick nickname`. If you don't hear from me in this place within the week, that should have done the job ;)

Comment: Last comment (at least I think so): the timer did it. Now it's day 7 after adding it, and it never failed. So use Journeymans solution above, but replace the second command (/nick username) with **/timer 5 nick username**. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin to handle automatic ghosting and identification. Just put the *.py file in your xchat scripts folder `~/.xchat2/`

https://github.com/Sepero/xchat_auto_ghost